# apache .htaccess remove everything after .php

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

i am trying to have all sites come up as site.php instead of site.php?abc=1...etc

currently my .htaccess file reads:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]`
`Options -Indexes`
But this is not working. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site.php? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Tested with apache2

Answer (score 1):

For every page (not only "site.php"), you can use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) $1?
```